# SSL/TLS CA and CSR's common name field problem when setup local https server

Tags: go, ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to setup local https server to test something.

```
➜  certs openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.cert.pem
Country Name (2 letter code) []:.
State or Province Name (full name) []:.
Locality Name (eg, city) []:.
Organization Name (eg, company) []:.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []:goose.local
Email Address []:.

➜  certs openssl req -new -sha256 -key goose.local.key -out goose.local.csr
Country Name (2 letter code) []:.
State or Province Name (full name) []:.
Locality Name (eg, city) []:.
Organization Name (eg, company) []:.
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:.
Common Name (eg, fully qualified host name) []goose.local                                                          S Email Address []:.
```

then i implement local https server as golang.
after installing CA to my device (laptop and iphone), when i access to my server (https://goose.local), it prompt `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.
how to set common name field in my case?
here is `openssl s_client` test for this.

```
➜  build openssl s_client -connect goose.local:443
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=0 CN = goose.local
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = goose.local
verify return:1
write W BLOCK
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=goose.local
   i:/CN=goose.local
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=goose.local
issuer=/CN=goose.local
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 2028 bytes and written 351 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Start Time: 1671011873
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: I'd try first verifying using `openssl s_client` which is able to connect to a TCP service which speaks TLS and perform the handshake with it while telling you what is happening in any concievable level of detail. If you make it work OK, the problem is probably in the way you have told your browser where's the cert of your CA is.

Comment: @kostix i update `openssl s_client` test for this.

Comment: The handshake went well (`Verify return code: 0 (ok)`), so you probably has to dig up what's up with registering the CA's cert in your browser.

Comment: The hostname must appear in the appropriate subjectAltName extension of the server certificate.